# Cannot play Blocks That Matter indie bundle game

Tags: java, games, jdk

I have installed latest JDK 1.7.0_u1 using the method provided at this page [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html).

I have also extracted the deb setup I got and edited the control file so as not to install java6.

I'm getting the following error when i run using:
`java -jar /opt/BlocksThatMatter/BTM.jar`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:82)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:99)
        at org.lwjgl.util.Timer.<clinit>(Timer.java:50)
        at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.<init>(Game.java:19)
        at org.flixel.FlxFactory.<init>(FlxFactory.java:74)
        at SSS.BTM.Main.BlocksThatMatter.main(BlocksThatMatter.java:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on this.

For now, what you can try is:

- open terminal
- move to the game folder:

cd /opt/BlocksThatMatter/

- allow executable rights on the BTM executable:

chmod +x BTM
(may requires admin rights: sudi chmod +x BTM)

- add update your path:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/lib/amd64"

(this may vary depending: your processor architecture ; if you are using the OpenJDK, or the Oracle non-free ; the place where you installed your java machine)
For example, it can also be export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/java/jre/lib/amd64"

- then try ti run the game with

./BTM

Hope this temporary workaround helps.

Comment: This makes the game works but i have to run the export command everytime

Comment: Try launching it from Desura client for Linux (it's in beta, you have to require an invite to have access) http://www.desura.com/
It'simple and it just works.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed that game and it runs with openjdk-6 (6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5) supplied in Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit (also on 11.04). There is no need to install Oracle Java if you only want to run this game. I didn't need to make BTM executable (installed blocks-matter_1.0.0.6_all.deb) it just run when started from the shortcut.